# To find median of numbers input in an array

Tags: c, arrays

Hi Community of Coders/Programmers,

I am trying to solve a problem having mix of everything, from sorting to using array, to finding length of array.

I'm trying to figure out median of numbers input in an array of strings, then converted to int array. Even array and odd array both have a different median.

While dry-running, I enter array as `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But the result I get is `0`. What could be the error in debugging it, any variable which is left uninitialised?

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE 1;
#define FALSE 0;

int arrayeven_median(int[], int);
int arrayodd_median(int[], int);
int stringlen(char[]);
int *sort(int[], int);

int num[100];
char numbers[100];
char string[100];
int sortednum[100];

int main()
{
    printf("Enter array of numbers separated by comma\n");

    gets(numbers);

    char *pt;
    /* get the first token */
    pt = strtok(numbers, ",");

    /* walk through other tokens */
    while (pt != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        num[i] = atoi(pt);
        sortednum[i] = *sort(&num[i], stringlen(numbers));
        pt = strtok(NULL, ",");
        i++;
    }

    if (stringlen(numbers) % 2 == 0)
        printf("%d", arrayeven_median(sortednum, stringlen(numbers)));
    else
        printf("%d", arrayodd_median(sortednum, stringlen(numbers)));
    return 0;
}

int stringlen(char string[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
        ;
    return i;
}

int *sort(int x[], int n)
{
    int hold, j, pass;
    int switched = TRUE
    ;

    for (pass = 0; pass < n - 1; pass++)
    {
        switched = FALSE
        ;
        for (j = 0; j < n - pass - 1; j++)
            if (x[j] > x[j + 1])
            {
                switched = TRUE
                ;
                hold = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j + 1];
                x[j + 1] = hold;
            }
    }
    return x;
}

int arrayeven_median(int x[], int n)
{
    int m1 = n / 2;
    int m2 = (n / 2) + 1;
    int median = (x[m1] + x[m2]) / 2;
    return median;
}

int arrayodd_median(int x[], int n)
{
    int m1 = (n / 2) + 1;
    int median = x[m1];
    return median;
}
```

Comment: `#define FALSE 0;` can lead to confusion because of the `;` at the end.

Comment: ... better to `#include <stdbool.h>` and use `false` and `true`. Your way requires the `;` to be omitted in `switched = FALSE` and would get in trouble with say `if(switched == FALSE)`

Comment: Note: `gets` is obsolete.

Comment: It seems you sort `stringlen` elements of your array (and you sort way too often and slow). So with `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`as input, you sort 13 numbers, when you really only have 7, padded in the array with zeroes for the remaining numbers.  In fact, you sort a completely wrong portion of the array in each round, staring at the currently scanned value and extending to the 13 numbers starting from there. Thus, you end up with even mre than 6 zeroes at the beginning of your final array.

Comment: `stringlen(numbers)` is always passing the original input string, now broken by `strtok`. Did you mean `stringlen(pt)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int arrayeven_median(int *, int);
int arrayodd_median(int *, int);
int *sort(int[], int);

int num[100];
char numbers[100];
char string[100];
int index1;

int main()
{
    printf("Enter array of numbers separated by comma\n");

    if (!fgets(numbers, sizeof numbers, stdin)) {
        printf("no input\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char *pt;
    /* get the first token */
    pt = strtok(numbers, ",");
    int i = 0;
    /* walk through other tokens */
    while (pt != NULL)
    {    
        num[i] = atoi(pt);
        pt = strtok(NULL, ",");
        i++;
        if(pt == NULL)
            index1 = i;
    }



    if (index1 % 2 == 0)
        printf("%d", arrayeven_median(sort(num, index1), index1));
    else
        printf("%d", arrayodd_median(sort(num, index1), index1));

    return 0;
}

int *sort(int x[], int n)
{
    int hold, j, pass;
    int switched = TRUE;

    for (pass = 0; pass < n - 1; pass++)
    {
        switched = FALSE;
        for (j = 0; j < n - pass - 1; j++)
            if (x[j] > x[j + 1])
            {
                switched = TRUE;
                hold = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j + 1];
                x[j + 1] = hold;
            }
    }

    return x;
}

int arrayeven_median(int *x, int n)
{
    int m1 = n / 2;
    int m2 = (n / 2) + 1;
    printf("%d\n", m1);
    int median = (x[m1-1] + x[m2-1]) / 2;
    return median;
}

int arrayodd_median(int *x, int n)
{
    int m1 = (n/2) + 1;
    int median = x[m1-1];
    return median;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are problems in your code:

- You keep storing the converted number to the first element of the array. `i` should be initialized outside the `while` loop.
- `sortednum[i] = *sort(&num[i], stringlen(numbers));` makes no sense: `stringlen(numbers)` computes the length of the input string in characters, yet this input string was truncated by `strtok()` and it is irrelevant for the `sort` function anyway that expects the number of elements in the `int` array.  You should instead store the value at the end of the `int` array and sort this array once all values have been stored.
- `#define TRUE 1;` is incorrect: `TRUE` will expand to `1;` instead of `1`, potentially causing syntax errors.
- the `sort` function does not use the `switched` flag to break early from the outer loop if the array is sorted.
- function `gets()` has been removed from the C standard because it cannot be used safely as it is not given the size of the destination array. Use `fgets()` instead.
- The arrays should be defined local to the `main` function, unless they are very large and should then be allocated.
- `arrayodd_median()` does not return the median element. It even accesses beyond the boundaries of the array if `n == 1`.
- you should test for invalid or incomplete input.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int arrayeven_median(int[], int);
int arrayodd_median(int[], int);
void sort(int[], int);

int main(void) {
    char numbers[100];
    int num[100];
    int i;
    char *pt;

    printf("Enter array of numbers separated by comma\n");

    if (!fgets(numbers, sizeof numbers, stdin)) {
        printf("no input\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* get the first token */
    pt = strtok(numbers, ", \n");
    if (pt == NULL) {
        printf("no numbers\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* walk through all tokens */
    for (i = 0; i < 100 && pt != NULL; i++) {
        /* convert the token string to an `int` and store at the end of the array */
        num[i] = atoi(pt);
        /* parse the next token */
        pt = strtok(NULL, ", \n");
    }

    /* sort the int array in place */
    sort(num, i);

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        /* array length is even, find the median value */
        printf("%d\n", arrayeven_median(num, i));
    } else {
        /* array length is odd, find the median element */            
        printf("%d\n", arrayodd_median(num, i));
    }
    return 0;
}

void sort(int x[], int n) {
    int hold, j, pass;

    for (pass = 0; pass < n - 1; pass++) {
        int switched = FALSE;
        for (j = 0; j < n - pass - 1; j++) {
            if (x[j] > x[j + 1]) {
                switched = TRUE;
                hold = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j + 1];
                x[j + 1] = hold;
            }
        }
        if (!switched) {
            break out of the loop if the rest of the array is sorted */
            break;
        }
    }
}

int arrayeven_median(int x[], int n) {
    int m = n / 2;
    return (x[m] + x[m + 1]) / 2;
}

int arrayodd_median(int x[], int n) {
    return x[n / 2];
}
```

Notes:

- `atoi` does not handle overflow: passing a string that represents very large numbers may cause unexpected behavior.
- `arrayeven_median` has a potential arithmetic overflow: on 32-bit systems, it will produce an incorrect result for input `2147483647,2147483647`

Comment: Enter array of numbers separated by comma
12,34,99,88,36,100
93

This is what I input as an array, and I am getting result as 93, but even array having (36+88)/2 is not 93, then what is your logic doing exactly?

Comment: I think the reason is array is not getting sorted.

Comment: @SwatiSharma: my apology, there was some confusion because of unused arrays. I fixed the code.

Comment: Your sort function has return type void, it doesn't return anything. The sorted array, can't be found.

To add, I can't figure your revised solution.

Thanks.

Comment: A sort function need not return anything -- the array is sorted in place. After the call to `sort (num, i);` the `num` array should now be sorted.

Comment: @SwatiSharma: I added some comments to clarify the steps.